# Trying to use variable to pass a view argument/parameter

Tags: views, theming

I'm currently in the middle of trying to figure out a way to pass the value from a variable to be used as parameter/argument for my drupal view.

I have a contextual filter that currently configured on my drupal view to output only nodes based on the taxonomy term/ID. Instead of explicitly manually setting the parameters below.

```
{{drupal_view('view_one', 'block_1', 212, 210)}}
```

Is there a way I could use a variable to pass the parameters to my drupal view

```
 % for tags in node.field_filter_tags %}

    {% set tagid = tags.entity.id %}

{% endfor %}

{{drupal_view('view_one', 'block_1', tagid)}}
```

I tried it but it seems to show duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

the first you install module [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak)

In file `yourtheme.theme`

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() 
 */
function yourtheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $terms=[];
  foreach($variables['node']->field_tags->getValue() as $term){
    $terms[] = $term['target_id'];
  }
  $variables['node_terms'] = implode(',',$terms);
}
```

In file `node.html.twig`

```
{{ drupal_view('custom_view','article_block',node_terms) }}
```

Config Views `CONTEXTUAL FILTERS` in your views
[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, the only issue I'm currently experiencing that it seems to be rendering duplicates. I have already enable `Distinct` in the `Query Settings`